# ExtractAll method fails when adding extra folder to the path

Tags: python, python-requests, pycharm, python-zipfile

I used requests module and extracted a zip from a server.
I need to extract it, and store it in a folder.

I create a sample directory and extract the file using :

```
prep_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(response.content))
prep_zip.extractall(final_directory)
print(response.status_code)
print('The library '+name+'has been extracted in '+final_directory) 
## final_directory = C:\\Users\XXXX\PycharProjects\Project1\ctl
```

When doing the above, all files are cleanly extracted and I can see the content inside ctl.

However, I want to create a subdirectory within ctl. eg: ctlA.
So the folder structure is: `C:\\Users\XXXX\PycharProjects\Project1\ctl\ctlA\`

I want to extract all files to the new path

```
another_directory=os.path.join(final_directory, r'ctlA')
prep_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(response.content))
prep_zip.extractall(another_directory)
print(response.status_code)
print('The library '+name+'has been extracted in '+final_directory)
```

This gives rise to a failure:
Error message :

```
 File "C:\XXXX\Python38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1647, in extractall
    self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "C:\XXXX\Python38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1701, in _extract_member
    open(targetpath, "wb") as target:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\XXXX\\PycharmProjects\\Project1\\ctl\\ctlA\\resources\\project\\Root.type.Files\\lib.type.File\\use-Lib.type.File\\{762f94cf-ed27-43e9-a0eb-39bbe5712253}.type.File\\Code Cache.type.File\\js.type.File\\index-dir.type.File\\1.type.DIR_SIGNIFIER.xml'
```

How is adding another folder to the path, failing the extract method?

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that your path does not exist or the user trying to access it is lacking the necessary privileges.

Comment: Is your file path too long? 256 usable after the drive characters and termination character? see https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-10/enable-long-file-name-support-windows-10, your code work fine on linux but C:\\Users\\XXXX\\PycharmProjects\\Project1\\ctl\\ctlA\\resources\\project\\Root.type.Files\\lib.type.File\\use-Lib.type.File\\{762f94cf-ed27-43e9-a0eb-39bbe5712253}.type.File\\Code Cache.type.File\\js.type.File\\index-dir.type.File\\1.type.DIR_SIGNIFIER.xml' is long